# Невозможно отключить использование данных о моих действиях на сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, настройки-профиля, приватность

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

При попытке отключить просто обновляется страница.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответствующий баг-репорт на MSE: [Can't disable usage of my on-site activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328058/339911)

Comment: Там и галочка какая-то отличная от других галок

Comment: @αλεχολυτ совпадение.jpg?

Comment: Вот [скрин с MSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpMSB.jpg) на моём iPad.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у меня, кстати, раньше эта галка была выключена. А теперь вот включена. Недобросовестно себя ведут )=

Comment: Во всём виноваты , это их ошибка. Это не наша ошибка.

Comment: А вообще, раньше и галочки-то не было никакой, поэтому на переходном периоде вполне вероятны всякие приколы (как обычно).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ эта галка раньше вроде в другом месте была. Не?

Comment: Хз, помню, что текст описания недавно переводил, поэтому и считаю, что недавно запилили. Можно было выкачать файлик раньше, а вот про отключение не помню такого.

Comment: Там еще для «Active» нужно контекст добавить для перевода, а то «Текущие» какие-то получились.

Comment: Проблема [была устранена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328485/260198).